# app.auth(...).signInWithCredential is not a function firebase error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'm trying to add google login to my node js firebase app. I'm getting the following error:
app.auth(...).signInWithCredential is not a function

Here's the code on the server

```
    var credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(id_token);
    return app.auth().signInWithCredential(credential);
```

On the client

```
 // We need to register an Observer on Firebase Auth to make sure auth is initialized.
        var unsubscribe = app.auth().onAuthStateChanged((firebaseUser) => {
            unsubscribe();
            // Check if we are already signed-in Firebase with the correct user.
            // Build Firebase credential with the Google ID token.
            var credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token);
            // Sign in with credential from the Google user.
            firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential).catch( (error) => {
                // Handle Errors here.
                var errorCode = error.code;
                var errorMessage = error.message;
                // The email of the user's account used.
                var email = error.email;
                // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
                var credential = error.credential;
                console.dir(errorMessage);
            }).then( (success) => {
                console.dir(success);

                var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;

                axios.post('/auth/google-login', {
                    id_token: id_token
                }).then(response => {
                    var result = response.data;
                    if (result.status === "ok") {
                        this.setState({complete: true});
                    } else if (result.error) {
                        this.setState({error: result.error});
                    }
                }).catch(error => {
                    console.dir(error);
                    this.setState({error: "error"});
                });
            });
        });
```

What I'm I doing wrong?

At the top of the nodejs file, I have

```
var app = require('./base');
```

where base :

```
var serviceAccount = require("./service-account-file.json");

const app =   fadmin.initializeApp({
    credential: fadmin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "https://test.firebaseio.com"
});
module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show what you did to integrate Firebase Authentication.

Comment: So you're using the Firebase Admin SDK?  How exactly did you add that to your project?  What version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Hi there are hints that the problem starts with node version 6.21. that 
app.auth().signInWithCredential(credential)
Don't work

It works in v6.2.0.

Try signInWithEmailAndPassword 
Use latest version of node

Comment: is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

The function [`signInWithCredential`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#sign-inwith-credential) is part of the [Firebase JavaScript SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js)

> The Firebase JavaScript SDK implements the ***client-side*** libraries used by applications using Firebase services.

The [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) is intended to run on a server or other privileged environment. *The Admin SDK does not include sign-in functions.*

Comment: how do I initialize both the admin sdk and firebase sdk using initialize app?

Comment: @LouisaScheinost See [**Add Firebase to your JavaScript project**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) and [**Add the Firebase Admin SDK to Your Server**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup)